# Is there a way to use the new UIPresentationController with push/pop transitions, not just modal?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uipresentationcontroller

It seems all the docs I've read refer to using the new `UIPresentationController` with modal presentations, but none refer to `UINavigationController`-based push/pop transitions. Are these possible with iOS 8, if so, how do I present them?